# Cordova Plugin Pedometers

Tags: cordova, pedometer

I try to put this plugin on my Android app 
https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-pedometer

I put this on my OnDeviceReady :

```
var successHandler = function (pedometerData) {

alert(pedometerData.numberOfSteps);

};
pedometer.startPedometerUpdates(successHandler, onError);
```

I tried several code but it doesnt work,

Someone has a solution please

Answer (score 0):

check that plugin is properly installed with :

```
cordova plugin list
```

If you do not see it in the list, run:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-pedometer
```